# ngFor and ngIf on bootstrap columns

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I want to hide and show bootstrap columns inside a row based on search value.

Here is a simple template:

```
<div class="container py-5">
  <p class="text-center"><input type="text" placeholder="search" [(ngModel)]="searchVal"></p>
  <div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let val of values" class="col-4 my-2">
      <ng-container *ngIf="val.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchVal.toLowerCase())!=-1">
        {{val}}
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the component:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  searchVal : string = "";
  values = ['Manager', 'Model', 'Teacher', 'Student'];
}
```

The ideal solution is to use ngFor and ngIf on column:

```
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let val of values" class="col-4 my-2" *ngIf="val.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchVal.toLowerCase())!=-1">
        {{val}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

But we all know that its not possible to use both on same element.

In the code I provide here, I used ng-container to solve this issue, however, since the ng-container is not inside the column, if a value does not match, the column remains displayed and its content is hidden which looks ugly. Try to write the letter "t" in the search field to see what I mean. The solution that I am looking for is to remove the entire column if its value does not match.

Here is a running code: https://angular-rgc8f7.stackblitz.io

Comment: when i type t I see student and Teacher, but there is space for others on left because of the bootstrap column css.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swap your `div` and `ng-container`:

`ng-container` has the `for` loop and `div` has the `if` condition

```
<div class="container py-5">
  <p class="text-center"><input type="text" placeholder="search" [(ngModel)]="searchVal"></p>
  <div class="row">    
      <ng-container *ngFor="let val of values">
        <div *ngIf="val.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchVal.toLowerCase())!=-1" class="col-4 my-2">
        {{val}}
        </div>
      </ng-container>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let val of values">  
  <div class="col-4 my-2" 
*ngIf="val.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchVal.toLowerCase())!=-1">
    {{val }}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just add a function in your component to dynamically filter the `values` before iteration. e.g

```
<div class="container py-5">
  <p class="text-center"><input type="text" placeholder="search" [(ngModel)]="searchVal"></p>
  <div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let val of filterValues(values, searchVal)" class="col-4 my-2">
      {{val}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your component;

```
filterValues(values: string[], searchVal: string) {
     return values.filter((val: string) => {
       return val.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchVal.toLowerCase())!=-1;
     });
  }
```

Change detection on your search value will cause a refilter, filtering on the current search value, and value list, and updating your table.

This way, you don't need the `ng-container` at all, and, if you ever need to filter based on other criteria too, you can do it all in one place :)

StackBlitz Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-miow53